# Weird issue with Macros and ARC

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macros, automatic-ref-counting, llvm

OK, so here's my issue...

**My Macro definitions**

```
#define DRK_INIT(X) -(id)init \
{ \
self = [super init]; \
if (self) { \
X \
} \
return self; \
}

#define DRK_DEALLOC(X) -(void)dealloc \
{ \
X \
[super dealloc]; \
}

#define DRK_DICFROMFILE(X)          [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:(X)]
#define DRK_MUTDICFROMFILE(X)       [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:(X)]
#define DRK_ARRFROMFILE(X)          [NSArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:(X)]
#define DRK_MUTARRFROMFILE(X)       [NSMutableArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:(X)]
#define DRK_STRFROMFILE(X)          [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:(X) encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil]

#define DRK_WRITESTRTOFILE(X,Y)     [(X) writeToFile:(Y) atomically:YES encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil]
#define DRK_WRITEDICTOFILE(X,Y)     [(X) writeToFile:(Y) atomically:YES]
#define DRK_WRITEARRTOFILE(X,Y)     [(X) writeToFile:(Y) atomically:YES]
```

Now, when I'm trying to use them (exactly as when I was *not* using ARC), like this, I keep getting warnings :

```
// Type specifier missing, defaults to 'int'
DRK_INIT();

- (void)someFunction:(NSString*)str
{
    // Implicit conversion of 'int' to 'NSString *' is disallowed with ARC
    [self setContent:DRK_STRFROMFILE(str)];
}
```

Any ideas what is going on? How could eliminate all these - actually harmless - warnings/errors?

---

**HINTS :**

- Please note that the whole thing was and is still working, though after converting to ARC, it keeps showing several warnings/errors.
- I'm running Xcode 4.5.1, Mac OS X 10.7.5 (Lion) and compiling with LLVM 4.1

Comment: curious why you are using macros in this fashion...

Comment: calling `-[super dealloc]` isn't allowed with ARC

Comment: Anyway, I don't get the warning using your DRK_INIT() macro as above--check your source before that point for errors...

Comment: @nielsbot OK, `DRK_DEALLOC` function is *not* currently in use in my ARC-enabled project (so, let's say I copy-pasted that in the question by mistake). As for my use of macros... I don't know - I'm generally a big fan of macros, especially when delivering the most essential of its various uses : replacing unnecessarily big chuncks of code which - given that they are going to be re-used numerous times - will finally "pollute" the code base.

Comment: ok--although it's sort of like you're replacing obj-c syntax with C syntax using macros... and macros have their own problems which are difficult to track down sometimes, this being one of those times.

Comment: If you really want to have a reusable code block inside your init methods, I use blocks instead.. Or a category on NSObject that provides a `-baseInit` methods or something like that.

Comment: @nielsbot Thanks for your suggestions. I finally managed to solve by - (talking about weird) - adding an extra `\\` escape at the *last* line of a multiline macro of mine (at some other place). And yep, no more warnings any more... :S

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that your definition of DRK_INIT expects an argument but you did not provide one.

You also have a ';' at the end of the DRK_INIT() invocation which will end up outside of any method definition.

Don't try to second-guess whats happening

Use the Preprocess option in XCode to see what you are actually generating.

Comment: I always suspected there would be an option for that `Product`->`Generate Output`->`Preprocessed File`, but couldn't actually spot it till now. Although my initial issue has **nothing** to do with the code (it was actually one of those time when `touch`ing the `.pch` file fixed *all* errors), I'll still accept this as an answer. Thanks mate!